# We have passed 100,000 posts on the main site!

Tags: discussion, statistics

I just noticed that we have now officially passed 100,000 posts on the main site, by post ID.

Thanks to all of you for contributing, and keeping contributing!

Comment: Is there a hat for it?

Comment: @Separatrix Not that I know of, unfortunately. No badge either. I considered pointing to post ID 100,000 or even 100,001, but felt that everyone's contributions are equally important, so decided against singling out a single post by a single user.

Comment: Especially since they just got lucky to be 100,000 not 99,999. ;)

Comment: Let's now set our sights on 1,000,000, *without* sacrificing quality!

Comment: So, I checked [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for some information, and it's telling me we only have ~14,000 questions and ~70,000 answers. So either the post ID count is messed up - which is my guess - or someone stole 16,000 posts. Perhaps we have 16,000 deleted posts that aren't showing up?

Comment: @HDE226868 A quick search turns up 7,187 deleted posts, but I don't know how that interacts with accounts that have been deleted and other edge cases. Truth to be told, I went by post ID expecting that to be a decent approximation of the total number of posts ever made...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I had just gone to search to check that. Well, it's certainly an order-of-magnitude approximation, which is fine by me.

Comment: Holy crap.  I am happy and astonished at the same time. I didn't know how well this site would work when we were pushing it through Area 51.  Nice job everyone.

Comment: If the numbering is across all posts, and if the scheme on the site matches what we see through SEDE, then tag wiks, tag wiki excerpts, mod nominations, and a few other things (what's a "privilege wiki"?) are also being counted.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I suspect you're on to something. That'd certainly be the right order of magnitude for the missing post IDs vs questions and answers.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I checked the worldbuilding database tables. While postId is over 100,000, there are only 91,817 posts of all types (including wikis and deleted and such). This was as of about three days ago (last postId in the database is 99799), but there is still a ~8,000 post gap somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently we haven't, quite yet.  The count in SEDE is correct (as of its last refresh).  I [asked about the discrepancy on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304559/162102) and learned that not all ID numbers are actually used.

We're close to 100k but not quite there yet.  I'm confident we'll remedy that before too long.

Comment: Grumble grumble grumble